# ¿Cómo comparar valor obtenido de un arreglo asociativo mediante "fetch_assoc()" con un número entero,dentro de un IF()?

Tags: php, mysql, array, if

aqui esta parte del código:

```
$sql = "select count(*) from usuarios where (username='$user' or email='$user') and password='$contra'";

$result = $con -> query($sql);

$row = $result -> fetch_assoc();

if(???????== 0){

    echo "<h1 style='text-align:center'>Ingreso invalido del sistema</h1>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<a style='text-align:center' href='index.html'>Volver a Intentarlo</a>";

}

else {}
```

Desde ya,muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Convendría en tu caso aplicar consultas preparadas para dar seguridad al código.

Uno no debe conformarse con que el código funcione, hay que preocuparse porque sea **seguro**. Aquí el peligro es que cualquier aprendiz de hacker puede manipular las variables `$user` o `$contra` para colarte una peligrosa inyección de código malicioso.

Para evitar eso el proceso es muy sencillo:

- Usamos marcadores `?` en la consulta
- Preparamos la consulta
- Pasamos los datos aparte mediante `bind_param`, de ese modo el sistema verificará si algún usuario mal intencionado los amañó

Luego, para obtener el dato que buscas:

- puedes usar `bind_result`, diciéndole que te ponga el resultado en esa variable (`$total` en este caso)
- invocamos a `fetch` para que coloque el puntero de los resultados sobre nuestra variable indicada en `bind_result`
- trabajos con `$total`
- cerramos recursos

El código sería este:

```
$sql = "select count(*) total from usuarios where (username=? or email=?) and password=?";
$stmt = $con -> prepare($sql);
if ($stmt) {
    /*
      * Pasar parámetros separados  de la instrucción SQL
      * Ejecutar
      * Almacenar los resultados
    */
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $user,$user,$contra);
    $stmt->execute();

    /*
      * Imprimir los  resultados
      *  asignándolos a  variables
    */

    $stmt->bind_result($total);
    $stmt->fetch();

    if($total== 0){

        echo "<h1 style='text-align:center'>Ingreso invalido del sistema</h1>";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<a style='text-align:center' href='index.html'>Volver a Intentarlo</a>";

    }else {
        echo "No hay datos";
    }

   /*
      * Cerrar  recursos
    */

    $stmt->close();

}else{

    echo "Error en la consulta";    

}
$con->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero un apunte: deberías comprobar que la query ha funcionado:

```
$result = $con -> query($sql);
if ($result != false) {
```

Para obtener el resultado de la consulta cuando se trata de una suma o un recuento se me ocurren un par de maneras. La primera es mediante un alias:

```
$sql = "select count(*) as recuento from usuarios ..."
...
if ($row['recuento'] ==...
```

Y la segunda sería usar otro método en lugar del método del array asociativo:

```
$row = $result -> fetch_row();
if ($row[0] ==...
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor que puedes hacer es poner un alias

```
$sql = "select count(*) AS alias from usuarios where (username='$user' or 
email='$user') and password='$contra'";

$result = $con -> query($sql);

$row = $result -> fetch_assoc();

if($row['alias'] === 0):

    echo "<h1 style='text-align:center'>Ingreso invalido del sistema</h1>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<a style='text-align:center' href='index.html'>Volver a Intentarlo</a>";

else:
    // Otra cosa
endif;
```